# <variable name='bookmark' type='BookmarkBeans'> is not defined consistently on alternative layout 'layout/item_bookmarks'

Tags: android, android-studio, data-binding

i have faced above issue in Android Studio this error belongs to Databinding.

i have many times cache invalidate and delete .gradle file and build but this issue not fixed yet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already faced this Error ( consistently on alternative layouts ) and solved in two steps

1. Invalidiate Cache
2. Restarting Computer. ---(this step is important)---